# Retrive data from ACF fields and show in frontend table in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to show a dynamic table in index.PHP which retrieve data from ACF field every time when new entry and display.I am new in php and does not know the exact method.
Here is my cod,

```
<div class="table">
  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Team', 'posts_per_page' => 20 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  `while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  ?>
  endwhile
  ?>
  <table class="tb1" style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <th > Name</th>
      <th >Email</th>
      <th >Phon no</th>
      <th >Designation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><?php  echo get_field('name');?></td>
      <td ><?php  echo get_field('email');?></td>
      <td><?php  echo get_field('phon_no');?></td>
      <td><?php  echo get_field('designation');?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: On the topic of correct usage of ACF, you should read
[ACF Docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) . Right now you code lacks way too much for the usage of ACF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here would be the recommended approach to using ACF in a normal loop. Note that your `while` statement is what sets up retrieving each entry, so anything you want to happen for each entry happens inside that loop.

```
<?php
  $args = array('post_type' => 'Team', 'posts_per_page' => 20);
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($loop->have_posts()): ?>
  <div class="table">
    <table class="tb1" style="width:50%">
      <tr>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phon no</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
      </tr>

      <?php while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php the_field('name');?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('email');?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('phon_no');?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('designation');?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile;?>
    </table>
  </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks to all for help

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
<div class="table">
  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Team', 'posts_per_page' => 20 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );  
  ?>
  <table class="tb1" style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <th >Name</th>
      <th >Email</th>
      <th >Phon no</th>
      <th >Designation</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td ><?php  echo get_field('name');?></td>
        <td ><?php  echo get_field('email');?></td>
        <td><?php  echo get_field('phon_no');?></td>
        <td><?php  echo get_field('designation');?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      endwhile?>    
  </table>
```